# Bug in 'Late Answers' Review Tab

Tags: bug, status-completed, review, late-answers

I was recently pestering mods by flagging everything I could find, when I came across this situation:
[image: Pic of not old question]

There was an answer in the 'late answers' tab that was posted on a question 3 minutes after it was asked.  The question wasn't old either; it was asked 5 minutes ago.

Comment: yeah .. the copy is not corresponding to the query ...

Comment: @Waffles, what does that mean?

Comment: the text is not corresponding with the actual query we are running, I need to discuss with Jeff what the desired behavior is and fix it up

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Wow, a 400 bounty on a very old meta post.  I see how this happened and needless to say - banned users will now no longer have their posts enter the late answers queue after the next build.

Comment: I think this happened on Workplace recently too..

Comment: It will be fixed everywhere when this is deployed.

Answer (score 3):

Corrected.

Late answers mean:

- The question was created **at least** 30 days prior to the answer
- The user answering has less than 10 rep

Comment: To be deployed later