# Is there a "Review" panel filter problem?

Tags: bug, review, filtering

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Bug in 'Late Answers' Review Tab](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78721/bug-in-late-answers-review-tab)

Under "Review," I filtered by [.net](/questions/tagged/.net), and clicked on "Late Answers," obtaining [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/review/late-answers?pagesize=15&filter=day&tag=.net).  One of the results is [How to reuse threads in .NET 3.5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5826981/how-to-reuse-threads-in-net-3-5/5827065#5827065).

How came this questions is considered old? The page reports "asked 14 hours ago."

Comment: Does a standard Earth day no longer have 24 hours?

Comment: @random Do you mean the question is old if it's asked more than a day ago?

Comment: You filtered by day, the answer was posted inside a day.

Comment: @random The *answer* was posted inside a day, but the *question* against which it was posted is not old in any way, so this answer should not have appeared on the Late Answers pane at all. Because the description says, "late answers to old questions provided by users with less than 10 reputation".

Comment: One hour is considered late on SO